# Is there a tidy way to read a JSON string and translate into new variables?

Tags: r, json

I have a JSON string that I would like to spearate into new variables. I feel there must be a clever way but I cannot find the solution.

```
df <- structure(list(subject = c("dtv85251vucquc45", "mcj8vdqz7sxmjcr0"
), response = c("{\"P0_Q0\":{\"aktiv\":2,\"bekümmert\":3,\"interessiert\":4,\"freudig erregt\":2,\"verärgert\":2,\"stark\":0,\"schuldig\":1,\"erschrocken\":1,\"feindselig\":1,\"angeregt\":2},\"P1_Q0\":{\"stolz\":1,\"gereizt\":1,\"begeistert\":2,\"beschämt\":2,\"wach\":1,\"nervös\":1,\"entschlossen\":1,\"ängstlich\":1,\"aufmerksam\":2,\"durcheinander\":2}}", 
                "{\"P0_Q0\":{\"aktiv\":1,\"bekümmert\":3,\"interessiert\":1,\"freudig erregt\":1,\"verärgert\":0,\"stark\":0,\"schuldig\":2,\"erschrocken\":0,\"feindselig\":0,\"angeregt\":1},\"P1_Q0\":{\"stolz\":2,\"gereizt\":0,\"begeistert\":1,\"beschämt\":0,\"wach\":2,\"nervös\":0,\"entschlossen\":0,\"aufmerksam\":2,\"durcheinander\":0,\"ängstlich\":0}}"
)), class = c("tbl_df", 
              "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

desired output:

```
output <- structure(list(subject = c("dtv85251vucquc45", "mcj8vdqz7sxmjcr0"
), aktiv = 2:1, bekümmert = c(3L, 3L), interessiert = c(4L, 
1L), freudig.erregt = 2:1, verärgert = c(2L, 0L), 
    stark = c(0L, 0L), schuldig = 1:2, erschrocken = 1:0, 
    feindselig = 1:0, angeregt = 2:1, stolz = 1:2, 
    gereizt = 1:0, begeistert = 2:1, beschämt = c(2L, 
    0L), wach = 1:2, nervös = 1:0, entschlossen = 1:0, 
    ängstlich = 1:0, aufmerksam = c(2L, 2L), durcheinander = c(2L, 
    0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

what kind of works (but not tidy):

```
j <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  j[[i]] <- as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(df$response[i]))
}

output <- data.frame(subject=df$subject, bind_rows(j))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jsonlite::stream_in` works well with this.

```r
library(dplyr)
jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(df$response), simplifyDataFrame = FALSE) %>%
  lapply(bind_cols) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  bind_cols(df[,1,drop=FALSE], .)
#  Imported 2 records. Simplifying...
#            subject aktiv bekümmert interessiert freudig erregt verärgert stark
# 1 dtv85251vucquc45     2         3            4              2         2     0
# 2 mcj8vdqz7sxmjcr0     1         3            1              1         0     0
#   schuldig erschrocken feindselig angeregt stolz gereizt begeistert beschämt
# 1        1           1          1        2     1       1          2        2
# 2        2           0          0        1     2       0          1        0
#   wach nervös entschlossen ängstlich aufmerksam durcheinander
# 1    1      1            1         1          2             2
# 2    2      0            0         0          2             0
```

or slightly refactored:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest
df %>%
  mutate(
    response = jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(response), simplifyDataFrame = FALSE),
    response = lapply(response, bind_cols)
  ) %>%
  unnest(response)
#  Imported 2 records. Simplifying...
# # A tibble: 2 × 21
#   subject      aktiv bekümmert interessiert `freudig erregt` verärgert stark schuldig erschrocken feindselig angeregt
#   <chr>        <int>     <int>        <int>            <int>     <int> <int>    <int>       <int>      <int>    <int>
# 1 dtv85251vuc…     2         3            4                2         2     0        1           1          1        2
# 2 mcj8vdqz7sx…     1         3            1                1         0     0        2           0          0        1
# # ℹ 10 more variables: stolz <int>, gereizt <int>, begeistert <int>, beschämt <int>, wach <int>, nervös <int>,
# #   entschlossen <int>, ängstlich <int>, aufmerksam <int>, durcheinander <int>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about 'clever', but {[rjsoncons](https://cran.R-project.org/package=rjsoncons)} implements 'jmespath' queries. I wrote a little helper function to convert from json to R via jmespath

```
from_jmespath = function(json, path) {
    rjsoncons::jmespath(json, path) |>
        jsonlite::fromJSON()
}
```

and then extracted the relevant information from the rows of your data frame

```
keys = from_jmespath(df$response[1], "*.keys(@)[]")
values = lapply(df$response, from_jmespath, "*.values(@)[]")
```

I then constructed a tidy tibble from the various components

```
tbl = dplyr::tibble(
    subject = rep(df$subject, each = length(keys)),
    key = rep(keys, nrow(df)),
    value = unlist(values)
)
```

A 'wide' version is

```
tbl |>
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "key", values_from = "value")
```

**Updated**

`j_pivot` treats `df$response` as a NDJSON (new-line delimited JSON, where each row is a JSON record, and pivots to a data.frame / tibble

```
> j_pivot(df$response, "P0_Q0", as = "tibble")
## # A tibble: 2 × 10
##   aktiv bekümmert interessiert `freudig erregt` verärgert stark schuldig
##   <int>     <int>        <int>            <int>     <int> <int>    <int>
## 1     2         3            4                2         2     0        1
## 2     1         3            1                1         0     0        2
## # ℹ 3 more variables: erschrocken <int>, feindselig <int>, angeregt <int>
```

so the complete solution is

```
df |>
    select('subject') |>
    bind_cols(j_pivot(df$response, "P0_Q0", as = "tibble"))
```